# Redirecting to another laravel project running on another port [Laravel]

Tags: laravel, redirect, port

I am relatively new in Laravel. Here is the problem I am facing-
I have two Laravel projects running on 2 different ports, one on port 8000 and another on port 5000 in localhost. I am trying to redirect from a url in port 5000 to another url which is under port 8000. I tried doing this-
return redirect('127.0.0.1:8000/sso/login');
But this results in making the url "localhost:5000/127.0.0.1:8000/sso/login" which is obviously not what I want. Is there a way to redirect to a different port in Laravel?

Comment: Why not establish a route `return redirect('routename');` ?

Answer (score 3):

you have to use "http://" as part of url in redirect method.

```
return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/sso/login');
```